# How can I make tests wait for Vert.x Verticle deployment to be completed

Tags: java, testing, junit, service, vert.x

I am implementing tests for my Vert.x application, but I am having issues in making Vert.x wait for the deploy of the Verticle in a graceful way. 
This is my @BeforeClass Method:

```
    @BeforeClass
public static void before(TestContext context) 
{
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();

    byte[] encoded;
    JsonObject config;

    try {
        encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/config.json"));
        config = new JsonObject(new String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset()));

        options.setConfig(config);
        jdbc = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config , "PostgreSQL");

        deployVerticle((result) -> loadTestData((result), jdbc), options);

        while (true)
            {
            if (vertx.deploymentIDs().size() > 0)
                break;
            }
    } catch 
    (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, here is the implementation for the deployVerticle and loadTestData methods:

```
private static void deployVerticle(Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> next, DeploymentOptions options) {


    vertx.deployVerticle(PostgreSQLClientVerticle.class.getName(), options, deployResult -> 
    {
        if (deployResult.succeeded())
        next.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
    });
}
private static void loadTestData(AsyncResult<Void> previousOperation, JDBCClient jdbc)
{
    if (previousOperation.succeeded())
    {
        jdbc.getConnection(connection -> {
            if (connection.succeeded())
            {
                connection.result().query(deleteTestDataGeneration, queryResult -> 
                {
                    connection.result().close();
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, right now I have a `while (true)` on the `before`method to hold the process and make sure the verticle is actually deployed.
Otherwise, when the tests start running, the verticle is not yet fully deployed and I get a `NullPointerException` trying to reach the resources.

I've tried many different approaches like using CompositeFuture or using Future.compose method to make the "before tasks" sequential and make the program hold for completion.
I achieved in making those tasks sequential but failed on holding the process until they are completed.

One of the issues is, I think, the fact that the deployVerticle method returns the `AsyncResult` with `succeeded == true` after every step of the "deploy procedure" is done, instead of when the Verticle is totally up.

Meaning that the process gets a successful result before everything is actually up...but this is just a wild guess.

Bottom-line: I would like to find a way to wait for the Verticle to be totally deployed before proceeding to perform the tests, without having to do the `while (true)`loop that I currently have in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is the `Async async = context.async();`. With that the unittest stays in the method until it is not set to complete. Then you are able to orchestrate your asychronous code to:

- first deploy the verticle
- then execute the loadtestGeneration
- set the async to complete so that, the other unittest methods already can access to your verticle without nullpointerexception

I also made some cleanup, check it out:

BeforeClass

```
  @BeforeClass
  public static void before2(TestContext context){
    Async async = context.async();
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    byte[] encoded;
    JsonObject config;

    try {
      encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/config.json"));
      config = new JsonObject(new String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset()));
      options.setConfig(config);
      jdbc = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config , "PostgreSQL");

      deployVerticle2(options)
        .compose(c -> loadTestData2(jdbc))
        .setHandler(h -> {
          if(h.succeeded()){
            async.complete();
          }else{
            context.fail(h.cause());
          }
        });

    } catch (IOException e){
      context.fail(e);
    }
  }
```

DeployVerticle

```
  private static Future<Void> deployVerticle2(DeploymentOptions options) {
    Future<Void> future = Future.future();

    vertx.deployVerticle(PostgreSQLClientVerticle.class.getName(), options, deployResult -> {
      if (deployResult.failed()){
        future.fail(deployResult.cause());
      }else {
        future.complete();
      }
    });

    return future;
  }
```

LoadTestData

```
  private static Future<Void> loadTestData2(JDBCClient jdbc){
    Future<Void> future = Future.future();

    jdbc.getConnection(connection -> {
      if (connection.succeeded()) {
        connection.result().query(deleteTestDataGeneration, queryResult -> {
          if(queryResult.failed()){
            connection.result().close();
            future.fail(queryResult.cause());
          }else{
            connection.result().close();
            future.complete();
          }
        });
      } else {
        future.fail(connection.cause());
      }
    });

    return future;
  }
```